# Merging inputs on my command

Tags: bash, binary

I have a numeric table for each letters in enlglish. Evey letter has random number. And my command converts theese random numbers to binary codes. But it can convert just 1 letter at the same time. I want to merge automaticily any words when i typed. Like apple, pen, table, ...

My command

```
#/bin/bash

echo "Write a letter"
read n
a=$(grep $n ~/Desktop/letter-table | awk '{print $2}')

echo `perl -e 'printf "%b\n",'$a`
```

Output

```
[hoovy@turbine Desktop]$ sh code-lang.sh
Write a letter
a
1111001
[hoovy@turbine Desktop]$ sh code-lang.sh
Write a letter
p
10010001
[hoovy@turbine Desktop]$ sh code-lang.sh
Write a letter
p
10010001
[hoovy@turbine Desktop]$ sh code-lang.sh
Write a letter
l
10010001
[hoovy@turbine Desktop]$ sh code-lang.sh
Write a letter
e
10111010
[hoovy@turbine Desktop]$
```

Comment: It's not clear what output you want.   If you are going to use perl at all, you should convert the whole script to perl.  The whole point of perl is to merge bash grep awk, etc.

Comment: I want convert words to use my binary converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the string. I have also removed your `grep` and `echo` since they were not needed:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a string:" -r string

for((i=0; i<${#string};i++)); do
  a=$(awk -v s="${string:$i:1}" '$1==s{print $2}' ~/Desktop/letter-table)
  perl -e 'printf "%b\n", $ARGV[0]' "$a"
done
```

Or, better, take the string as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
string="$*"

for((i=0; i<${#string};i++)); do
  a=$(awk -v s="${string:$i:1}" '$1==s{print $2}' ~/Desktop/letter-table)
  perl -e 'printf "%b\n", $ARGV[0]' "$a"
done
```

And run the script like this:

```
$ foo.sh apple
1111001
10010001
10010001
1111001
10111010
```

Comment: It worked! thanks :)

Comment: can i commit my github this project. I'll attirbute.